# IdentityServer3 and Angular4, force initial login

Tags: angular, oauth, identityserver3

We have a large project consisting of an Angular4 application for the FE, a .Net WebApi2 MVC application for the BE and an MVC5 application which has the IdentityServer3 framework embedded inside for the Authentication server.

We are working towards implementing a SSO platform.  The Angular project uses the angular-oauth2-oidc package to handle authentication.

So far, everything is working well however, the solution we have in place for forcing the user to login isn't robust.

If we call initImplicitFlow too early, nothing happens. Calling it after X amount of time redirects the application to the IdentityServer3 login page (as expected).

Our auth service looks something like this:

```
// Load Discovery Document and then try to login the user
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
    this.initialiseUser();
});

private initialiseUser(): void {
  // This method just tries to parse the token(s) within the url when
  // the auth-server redirects the user back to the web-app
  // It dosn't send the user the the login page
  this.oauthService.tryLogin({
    onTokenReceived: context => {
      const claims: any = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
      if (claims) {
        if (!this.currentUser) {
            this.currentUser = new AppUser();
        }
        this.currentUser.sub = claims.sub.trim();
        this.currentUser.given_name = claims.given_name.trim();
        this.currentUser.id_token = this.oauthService.getIdToken();
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.router.navigate(['/home/dashboard']);
      }
    },
  });
  this.onAuthServiceReady.emit(true);
}
```

Our Router module looks like this:

```
export class CoreRoutingModule {

  loginTried = false;

  constructor(public router: Router, public authService: AppAuthService, public http: Http) {
    this.authService.onAuthServiceReady.subscribe(() => {
      this.loginTried = true;
    });

    router.events.forEach((e) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
        let loginSpinner = setInterval(() => {
          if (!authService.currentUser && this.loginTried) {
            this.authService.login();
          }

          if (authService.currentUser) {
            clearInterval(loginSpinner);
          }
        }, 5000);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

The setInterval was running 4 times a second which worked until we tried on a very slow device where an infinite loop occurred.  I've changed it to 5 seconds, however, I don't feel this is a good solution.

One solution I can think is to have an allow anonymous homepage with an image and big login button, however, the first preference is to force the redirect to IdentityServer.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!